# Data type declaration in ML

Tags: function, types, ml

I'm reviewing some Scheme to ML conversions we had done in class awhile back, and I'm confused on why we did (or didn't) do something.  The first ML code becomes:

```
fun sub(x,y,nil) = nil
  | sub(x,y,z1::z2) = if (x = z1) then y :: sub(x,y,z2) else z1::sub(x,y,z2);
```

The 2nd one becomes:

```
datatype InputType=Null | Number of int  | Cons of InputType*InputType;

fun sub2(x,y,Null) = Null 
  | sub2(x,y,Number(z)) = if (x = z) then Number(y) else Number(z)
  | sub2(x,y,Cons(z1,z2)) = Cons(sub2(x,y,z1),sub2(x,y,z2));
```

I understand that the variable types need to be the same throughout the entire function.  Therefore, since there is type Null, number, and cons, they need to be combined in a data type.  However, with that logic, why does the first one not need a new data type?  Last I checked, type "Null" and type "Cons" are not the same thing....

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function simply uses the `list` type, which is predefined in the SML library as

```
datatype 'a list = nil | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

(where `::` is additionally declared to be infix). So same situation in both cases, really.

As an aside, note that `Null` or `Cons` are not types. They are data constructors, i.e., values.

Comment: Also, the parentheses around the `if` condition are redundant.

Comment: ah. so the only reason we made a new datatype is because "Number" isn't predefined (or is it?)?  And it had to be combined with the ones that are?

Comment: None of the constructors of `InputType` is defined. The datatype declaration declares the type name, as well as its three constructor names.